store information and recall it from local storage in chrome extension
as the popup page disappears every time it lose the focus  i try to add the information that i have it in "input area" at my popup.html to be stored in local storage but its not working with popup.js
popup.html
<body>
    <textarea id="inputArea" rows="40" cols="40" maxlength="200" autofocus style="background-color: #f0f0f0; border: 1px solid #ccc;">
       
        </textarea>
    <br>

popup.js
/ Function to initialize the input fields
function myInitCode() {
  const inputFields = document.querySelectorAll(".inputArea");

  // Load the last input from chrome.storage.local when the popup opens
  chrome.storage.local.get(['lastInputs'], (result) => {
      console.log('Loaded last inputs:', result.lastInputs); // Debug log
      if (result.lastInputs && result.lastInputs.length > 0) {  // Check if lastInputs exists and is not empty
          // Populate input fields with the last inputs
          result.lastInputs.forEach((inputValue, index) => {
              if (inputFields[index]) {
                  inputFields[index].value = inputValue;
              }
          });
      }
  });
}

// Check if the document is ready
if (document.readyState !== 'loading') {
  console.log('document is already ready, just execute code here');
  myInitCode();
} else {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      console.log('document was not ready, place code here');
      myInitCode();
  });
}

// Save the input to chrome.storage.local when the popup is closed
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", () => {
  const inputFields = document.querySelectorAll(".inputArea");
  const inputValues = Array.from(inputFields).map(input => input.value.trim());

  // Store the input values in chrome.storage.local
  chrome.storage.local.set({ lastInputs: inputValues }, () => {
      console.log('Last inputs saved:', inputValues); // Debug log
  });
});


all what i need is when ever i unload the popup.html to automated stor the text in the input area
and re loade it when i open the popup.html again

beforeunload doesn't work in the popup. Save the changes immediately using an input event listener.

thanks, i will try that and reput he new code for any further questions for other
